# Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric ONLY in WHERE

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this query....

```
SELECT  
    CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), ResultLevel),
    *
FROM    
    dbo.DrugTestResult
WHERE   
    DrugID = 'THC'
    AND ISNUMERIC(ResultLevel) = 1
    AND (CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), ResultLevel) >= 50
         AND CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), ResultLevel) <= 99999)
    AND CONVERT(DATE, AuditStamp) > '2014-1-1'
```

Which returns this error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric

When I comment this part of the where clause

```
AND ( CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), ResultLevel) >= 50
      AND CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), ResultLevel) <= 99999
    )
```

The data set is returned.

So the question is why does the `CONVERT` work in the `SELECT`, but not in the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 3):

Because the different elements of the WHERE clause can get evaluated in any order that the query processing engine deems fit, so it can try to evaluate the CONVERT() before it evaluates the ISNUMERIC().   Therefore it can try to convert data that can't be converted.

The SELECT list, on the other hand, is evaluated after the WHERE clause, so the ISNUMERIC() has eliminated values that can't be converted.

To avoid your error, you can put the ISNUMERIC() on an inner derived table, so that you only try to CONVERT() data that is numeric in your outer WHERE clause.

Comment: It might also be pointed out that ISNUMERIC is really pretty awful. It will return 1 for a lot of things that are very loosely numeric (ex. $1.5, 1e4, 0x1)

Answer (score 0):

Because there are one or more records that can't be converted as requested. If you run your query in SSMS it will execute the conversion in the select clause only for those rows displayed from the resultset, meanwhile the where clause is executed for all rows in the resultset to determine which rows are included in the resulset. To test this you can execute the query (without the where clause) and scroll down: once you reach the row that is messing you you will get the conversion error.

Hope this answers your question and explains that behavior.